# Differences/Advantages between async loading and putting script at the end of body

Tags: javascript, performance

Could anyone tell me what the advantages are between putting the next script tag right after the < body > element and putting it before < /body > element?

```
<script>
(function (){
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.async = true;
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "foo.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);}
());
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

## 2017 Edit

This answer is completely out-of-date. With http2 in modern browsers and module bundlers in our stacks, the direction is going more and more in having small bundles. Chunks that are loaded when and only when they are needed. Even more important in the days of mobile.

## Old answer

The optimal solution is a single javascript file which contains everything needed for the current page. Only one request means much better performance. And for production a single file can be compressed which is better than compressing multiple files.

Also, i'd stick to putting the script to the end of your html body because the html will be rendered and displayed even though the javascript isn't loaded yet.

A script tag with `async` will most probably behave differently in each browser (since it's a quite new feature), whereas putting a script at the end of your body should produce the same result in every major browser.

Here is a writeup of async loading of JavaScript: [Thinking Async](http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/)

Comment: but what is the different between putting at the end and putting at the beginning with async=true ?

Comment: what do you mean by `async=true`?